# Strange results of lxml xpath element search using string-value

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

Can't understand the results of the following xpath query:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
s = '<aaa><bbb>f<ccc>e</ccc>d</bbb></aaa>'
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(s))
print(tree.xpath('//bbb[.="fed"]')) #prints an empty list!
```

According to the XPath specification,

> The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.

So I expect to get *bbb* element.

Even more puzzled is that each of the following queries return *bbb*:

```
tree.xpath('//bbb[contains(.,"fed")]')
tree.xpath('//bbb[normalize-space(.)="fed"]')
tree.xpath('//bbb[string-length(.)=3]')
```

Where am I wrong? Or is it a bug in lxml?

Answer (score 0):

**//bbb[.="fed"]** XPath means you are expecting **bbb** tag which is having text as **fed**

Validate if your xpath is correct or do not return multiple value from same xpath.

Post your DOM/link if you like us to create a XPath for you

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Sure, I understand. The xml is in the string in the code above (cause it's just a simple example): '<aaa><bbb>f<ccc>e</ccc>d</bbb></aaa>'. And I just can't understand why '/bbb[.="fed"]' doesn't return the 'bbb' element. Anyway, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a bug. Now fixed (checked for lxml v. 4.5.1).